# Paper Clip - No route matches [GET]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I have a view where I can edit an Author and I can chose a photo for that author when I chose the photo and click the update button I get an error that says:

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/photos/original/missing.png"):

```
private
    def author_params
        params.require(:author).permit(:name, :photo)
    end
```

routes

```
 resources :quotes, only: [:index, :edit, :create, :destroy, :update]
 resources :authors, only: [:index, :show, :destroy, :edit, :update]
```

Author Model where photo is

```
has_many :quotes
has_attached_file :photo
validates_attachment_content_type :photo, :content_type => ["photo/jpg", "photo/png", "photo/jpeg"]
```

View

```
<%= form_for @author, html: {multipart: true},method: :patch do |f| %>
<p>
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
</p>
<p>
    <%= f.label :photo %>
    <%= f.file_field :photo %>
</p>
<p>
    <%= f.submit "Edit Author"%>
</p>
<% end %>
```

EDIT

Quotes Controller in which the author it's created

```
def create
    @author = Author.where(name: params[:name]).first_or_create
    @quote = Quote.new(quote_params)
    @quote.author = @author
    @quote.save
    redirect_to quotes_path
end
```

So an author when it's created It has just the name

Comment: Does your `Author` model has something more code than you posted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.
The problem was here on this line.

This:

```
validates_attachment_content_type :photo, :content_type => ["photo/jpg", "photo/png", "photo/jpeg"]
```

Should be:

```
validates_attachment_content_type :photo, :content_type => ["image/jpg", "image/png", "image/jpeg"]
```